# Getting news description with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, parsing, web, request, cheerio

I'm trying to get the text from the 'a' tag in every entry of this webpage

> https://hn.algolia.com/?query=apple&sort=byPopularity&prefix&page=0&dateRange=all&type=story

I have already parsed some webpages but I'm having issues with this one, here's my code.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://hn.algolia.com/?query=apple&sort=byPopularity&prefix&page=0&dateRange=all&type=story'
}, function(err, response, body) {
if (err) return console.error(err);

// Tell Cherrio to load the HTML
$ = cheerio.load(body);
// list = [];
// $('div[id="item-main"]').each(function(){
//   var href = $(this).find('div > div').attr('h2');
//   list.push(h2);
// });
$('item-title-and-infos').each(function() {
  var href = $('h2', this).attr('href');
  if (href.lastIndexOf('/') > 0) {
      console.log($('a', this).text());
  }
});
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the content is loaded asyncronously, first an almost empty page is loaded and after the content you are looking for will be loaded.

Just console.log the body on your request and you will see somethig like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='HNSearch'>
<head ng-controller='HeadCtrl'>
...
links and meta
...
</head>
<body>
<div id='main' ng-cloak role='main' ui-view>

! NO CONTENT HERE ! IT WILL BE LOADED AFTER

</div>
<script src="https://d3nb9u6x572n0.cloudfront.net/assets/application-70dfa2f5ecb75bc8dfaa8729257bcbf1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you inspect the web with google chrome, you will see that this link is called after:

```
https://uj5wyc0l7x-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/Item_production/query?x-algolia-api-key=8ece23f8eb07cd25d40262a1764599b1&x-algolia-application-id=UJ5WYC0L7X&x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20AngularJS%203.7.5
```

So finally i found this solution that may hep you:

```
request.post({
    url:'https://uj5wyc0l7x-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/Item_production/query?x-algolia-api-key=8ece23f8eb07cd25d40262a1764599b1&x-algolia-application-id=UJ5WYC0L7X&x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20AngularJS%203.7.5',
    body:'{"params":"query=apple&hitsPerPage=20&minWordSizefor1Typo=5&minWordSizefor2Typos=9&advancedSyntax=true&ignorePlurals=false&tagFilters=%5B%22story%22%5D&numericFilters=%5B%5D&page=0&queryType=prefixLast&typoTolerance=true&restrictSearchableAttributes=%5B%5D"}',
    gzip:true,
    headers:{
        accept:'application/json',
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language":"es-ES,es;q=0.8",
        "Cache-Control":"no-cache",
        Connection:"keep-alive",
        "Content-Length":258,
        "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Host:"uj5wyc0l7x-dsn.algolia.net",
        Origin:"https://hn.algolia.com",
        Pragma:"no-cache",
        Referer:"https://hn.algolia.com/?query=apple&sort=byPopularity&prefix&page=0&dateRange=all&type=story",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
    }
},
function (err,res,body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Now the body is a huge JSON file with all the data.
I hop this helps you.